# change to number of sequence for all the string find in column and change dateTime into date

Tags: python

i'm a python beginner i got a problem while excuting a code..
i have written a code in this way:In this program i'm able to get a sequence of no. for all the column but don't want a number for column date i don't know how to implement it.. please help me...

```
with open("input2.csv", 'r',encoding="utf8") as csvfile: 
            # creating a csv reader object 
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')


            data = {}
            for row in reader:
    #         print(row)
                for header, value in row.items():
                    try:
                        data[header].append(value)
                    except KeyError:
                        data[header] = [value]

            # Loop through all keys
            for key in data.keys():
                values = data[key]

                things = list(sorted(set(values), key=values.index))

                for i, x in enumerate(data[key]):
                    data[key][i] = things.index(x) + 1
    #                 print(data[key][i])
                    NewData=data[key][i]
                    print(NewData)

            with open("OuputFile.csv", "w") as outfile:
                writer = csv.writer(outfile)
                # Write headers
                writer.writerow(data.keys())
                # Make one row equal to one value from each list
                rows = zip(*data.values())
                # Write rows
                writer.writerows(rows)
```

for which a have taken input data like this:

```
 job_Id FirstName   LastName    Address     Email           Date/Time

  1 snehil      singh       marathalli  ss@gmail.com        12/10/2011:02:03:20
  2 salman      khan        marathalli  ss@gmail.com        12/11/2011:03:10:20
  3 Amir        khan        HSR     ar@gmail.com        11/22/2009:09:03:20
  4 Rakhesh     kumar       HSR     rakesh@gmail.com    09/15/2010:02:03:55
  5 Ram     sharma      marathalli  r@gmail.com     01/10/2014:12:03:20
  6 Shyam       shahi       BTM     ss@gmail.com        12/17/2012:01:03:20
  7 salman      khan        HSR     ss@gmail.com        11/08/2016:15:03:20
  8 Amir        khan        BTM     ar@gmail.com        07/10/2013:04:02:30
  9 snehil      singh       Majestic    sne@gmail.com       03/20/2018:02:03:20
```

In this program i have a certain columns in which following operations is needed such as: The FirstName and LastName column is replace with "Fullname" by using lambda function.
The Date/Time column shuld only print Date not time.
After doing this all the string should be replaced with squence of numbers and the duplicated should print same numbers..

The output should be like this:

```
job_Id  FullName    Address  Email  Date
    1   1            1         1    12/10/2011
    2   2            1         1    12/11/2011
    3   3            2         2    11/22/2009
    4   4            2         3    09/15/2010  
    5   5            1         4    01/10/2014
    6   6            3         1    12/17/2012
    7   2            2         1    11/08/2016
    8   3            3         2    07/10/2013
    9   1            4         5    03/20/2018
```

please help me to find this output any logic will be fine....**but without using Pandas Dataframe**

Comment: I recommend looking at the `pandas` library. `pandas.read_csv` and `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` should do almost everything you are trying in only two lines of code.

Comment: thnx for the suggestion sir but that is the problem i don't have to use pandas Dataframe otherwise it was easy for me to get that output... logic behind is pandas is not scalable and in future i have to use this code to read the bigger csv file...so please if possible can you tell me same way how to achieve it without using DataFrame..

Comment: `pandas` is scalable. You can read a large csv file in chunks by specifying a `chunksize` when reading the file.

Comment: ohk i got it sir but my task is to get the output without using Pandas dataframe thats why i was doing this way... please help me to do it i have tried with dataframe its working with that....but i need it to be work without dataframe...

Comment: And you don't care which `FullName` belongs to e.g. Number 6?

Comment: sir i don't understand your question Fullname is nothing but it will give the combination of Lastname and firstname so first it will combine that fullname like:Name_lambda_function = lambda x, y: x + ' ' + y  or any other way and then it will replace that all name with sequance of numbers if any repetation will b there then it will return the same number which is assigned earlier..I have written a code change that string to sequence of no. but date and fullname i don't understand how to do it...